# Initialize a UIImage with the path of an image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

I have in a sqlite database the complete path of an image, which is stored in the device, and I need to set a UIImage with that image.

Example:

```
NSLog(@"Path %@", imagePath);
```

Output:

```
/Users/Sk*****/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/15977219-DEFE-407A-BB80-72E188E18DD2/Documents/20-10-20111746.png
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path`

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Comment: Ok... I did this. The main reason why it wasn't working is... the UIImageView was hidden. I'm an idiot! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.0 code here..**

use `contentsOfFile`

```
imageView.image = UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
```

Comment: It's recommended to use UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath).

Comment: @user5685969 If you want to show the Image path in your device then you should use this one but your code is before version swift 3.0